# Magento - UPS "Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time."

Tags: magento, ups

I have two Magento stores...one is US based with Minnesota as a shipping origin. In this store UPS works just fine.

The second store is based in Europe with Italy as the shipping origin. In this case I can't get UPS to work no matter I try.

I've turned on debugging and have managed to solve a few different errors including:

```
2011-04-16T19:37:40+00:00 DEBUG (7): Cannot retrieve shipping rates  
2011-04-16T19:39:58+00:00 DEBUG (7): This measurement system is not valid for the selected country.  
2011-04-16T19:47:13+00:00 DEBUG (7): XML Rating and Service Selection Service Unavailable  
2011-04-16T20:49:22+00:00 DEBUG (7): Can't convert rate from "USD-EUR".  
2011-04-16T22:20:40+00:00 DEBUG (7): Cannot retrieve shipping rates
```

Now I'm at this point and I'm baffled and Google has been of no help. Does anyone here perhaps have a thought as to what might be the issue?

```
2011-04-17T15:55:03+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array  
(  
[request] => Array  
    (  
        [accept_UPS_license_agreement] => yes  
        [10_action] => 4  
        [13_product] => GNDRES  
        [14_origCountry] => IT  
        [15_origPostal] => 20144  
        [origCity] => Milan  
        [19_destPostal] => 28026  
        [22_destCountry] => ES  
        [23_weight] => 16  
        [47_rate_chart] => One Time Pickup  
        [48_container] => 00  
        [49_residential] => 01  
        [weight_std] => kgs  
    )    
[result] => UPSOnLine5%Unsupported country specified%6920  
[__pid] => 8232  
)
```

Comment: its pretty clear that you are trying to set up UPS for the country not supported and your magento and UPSP configurations are clashing

Comment: Not really a helpful answer is it?  I mean, I can also read...the question is why is this particular error occurring? I have the exact same set of information working just fine in the live OSCommerce install. Any thoughts on where the conflict might be taking place?

Comment: well it's a comment and not an answer so I would better check what are my metrics settings and why they are wrong , why I don't have currency rates in my system so the conversion would be possible and so on. Please add your magento version to the question (every time).

Comment: Good point on the Magento version: it's 1.5.0.1.  Those 1st 5 bugs have been fixed, I guess I wasn't clear about that. But it's the unsupported country one that's killing me.

Comment: well, try leaving shipping origin blank and see if it works, Italy is not supported

Comment: Interesting thought...I tried it but no luck. In the end it would appear that the issue is that Magento is using ISO2 codes for the destination countries and UPS is looking for ISO3. So ES is being sent, ESP is what needs to be received. There's an extension called MatrixRates which I'm trying out now which will easily allow me to set up table rates which isn't a bad idea altogether. I'm going to see if I can that working and report back.

Comment: @nero - That ISO info is useful, you should edit your question to include it and ask about possible fixes.

Comment: Yes I am also having the same issue in Magento 2.2.4 [Please see the thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57332893/magento-2-2-4-sorry-no-quotes-are-available-for-this-order-at-this-time)

Answer (score 2):

Magento2 has this issue/feature present as well. 
The thing is, UPS in CGI mode will accept only US as the origin country.