# Magento 2.2.4: "Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time"

Tags: magento2, shipping-method

The checkout was working smoothly and I've checked the test orders in admin panel. While during the maintenance I clean up the cache and upgrade the static content.

Right after unexpectedly, I am getting message at the time of checkout "Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time". I have configured UPS shipping method under configuration.

You can also replicate it, by accessing the website at https://awscales.com

I have also tried cache clean, re-index but no luck. I am unable to figure out the possible reason of this message.

My environment setup is:

OS: Ubuntu (VERSION-16.04.4)

PHP: 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.5

Zend: Engine v3.0.0

Magento: 2.2.4 (changed to developer mode)

While I access admin panel and open 'Sales > Shipping Method' tab from 'Store > Configuration', I noticed that the page is not working at all. The 'Save' button is also disabled.

In browser console I saw the following error:

TypeError: $(...).phpConfigEditor is not a function

I am clueless, please help.